# Windows Phone 7 how do I change the text size on "pin to start" menu icon

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Is there a way to make the text smaller in the manifest?  My "Title" is running off the end of the icon....

```
 <Tokens>
  <PrimaryToken TokenID="MyVirtualHealthCheckToken" TaskName="_default">

    <TemplateType5>
      <BackgroundImageURI IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">vhcBackground.png</BackgroundImageURI>
      <Count>0</Count>
      <Title>MyVirtualHealthCheck</Title>
    </TemplateType5>

  </PrimaryToken>
</Tokens>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the text size can't be changed. You'll have to shorten the title. Or, you could create a tile icon that has your app's name written, similar to the official `Office` tile.

Comment: It doesn't seem to want to let me leave the title blank...in the WMAppManifest.xml file...

Comment: @Jarrette: Try adding one or more spaces